# Adding JSON results within quotation marks in a dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to the JSON values from a JQuery Ajax request into a dataset.  The problem is that the dataset is in quotation marks and will not accept my parsed JSON values.

This is the original dataset:

```
{"value":"B", "number":"1492"},
{"value":"C", "number":"2782"},
{"value":"D", "number":"4253"},
{"value":"E", "number":"2702"}
```

I need for it to be accept the parsed JSON from the JQuery call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ButtonClick").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://myUrl.com",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        {"value":data.name, "number": data.currency},
        {"value":data.nameA, "number":data.currencyA},
        {"value":data.nameB, "number":data.currencyB},
        {"value":data.nameC, "number":data.CurrencyC}
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for JSON.parse? Having values in quotation marks is both valid JSON notation (when stringified) and valid JavaScript. Maybe you can clarify what your problem is.

Comment: Both your _original dataset_ and whatever that is in the `success` callback don't make any sense from a procedural or data-structure perspective. It would help if you explain (in words) what it is you're trying to accomplish

Comment: The problem is that the dataset is in quotation marks and will not accept my parsed JSON values

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean. What does _"will not accept"_ mean? Again, please explain what it is you're trying to do, **not** what you perceive the problem to be

Comment: "will not accept" means there are blank values, when there is clearly data there.

Comment: If that really is your original dataset, it's not even valid JSON,.  maybe if wrapped in an array it might make more sense.  And what are you trying to do in your success callback, it's not valid Javascript either.

Comment: you are missing the point.  I need to place parsed JSON data within quotation marks.

Comment: From the number of questions asked in comments, it should show you that there is not enough detail in this post. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54875966/edit) to include a) actual valid data structures, b) actual valid JS code, and c) the state you want both before and after this AJAX request completes

Comment: Are you trying to display the result in a dataframe of some kind?